# Can't get my SQL query to filter by dates like I want

Tags: sql-server, format

I have a query where I want to exclude rows if a date column has any one of a set of dates.

I am having trouble figuring how to return the correct result sets without filtering one month at a time.

My initial attempts assumed the operator '!=' would be able to specify multiple variables, but I might be mistaken.

How do I filter the results in such a way that removes all the specified dates I do not want?

```
SELECT * INTO IPS_TransactionDataAll2
FROM
[IPS_TransactionDataAll1]
where Format([Start Date], 'MM/yyyy') != ('07/2016''08/2016''09/2016''10/2016''11/2016''10/2016''01/2017''02/2017''03/2017''04/2017''05/2017''06/2017''07/2017')
```

Pseudo-code:

Select into TableB
from TableA
Where dates not in the months 7-11/2016 and 1-7/2017

Comment: What SQL Engine are you using?

Comment: @DanielBjörk The original screenshot that I replaced with text was of (MS) SSMS, so I've added a 
 [sql-server] tag.

Comment: Why don't you do use a where clause something like `WHERE [Start Date] NOT BETWEEN DATE '2016-07-01' AND DATE '2017-07-31'` ?

Answer (score 10):

`!=` doesn't support a list of items like that.

Try one of these (note the commas between items):

```
WHERE Format([Start Date], 'MM/yyyy') NOT IN ('07/2016','08/2016','09/2016',...)
```

or even better (and faster), without converting to text (if your date range is truly consecutive like your example):

```
WHERE [START Date] NOT BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
```

Since between is inclusive of the endpoints, that is equivalent to:

```
WHERE [START Date] >= '2016-07-01' 
AND   [START Date] <  '2017-08-01'
```

Comment: Might want to do '2017-07-31 23:59:59' in the BETWEEN where clause, as any records at midnight (8/1/17) would be excluded (Especially if there is functionality that truncates time off).

Comment: @MguerraTorres Yep, that's what I was suggesting with the "endpoints" comment, but I'll include your suggestion.

Comment: My apologies!  I only focused on the BETWEEN segment as it's my "go-to" and the first approach I'd take.